# Must a JCP/SCJP exam question be complete (i.e. compilable)?

Tags: java, scjp

Just reading Kathy "Sierra/Bert Bates: JSCP Java6 Study Guide" and found contradicting mock exam questions:

In one of the self-test questions, the correct answer was "Code does not compile" due to the fact that there were no import statements in the code nor was "given the correct import statements" in the question itself. They tell you explicitly afterwards to expect such tricky questions.

In a question later, where the code contained only a correctly defined main method, I picked "code does not compile" because there was no surrounding class declaration. However this wasn't the correct answer, the code was supposed to run.

So my question: how to know which questions are expected to compile if source code is not fully provided?

Another question about the exam: are the questions grouped by any means (e.g. topic, difficulty etc.) or do they come completely at random?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific certification exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question (after successfully passing the test):

- Beginning the exam there is a textual description that fully defines how the exam is assessed/graded.
- For each question you will now exactly how many answers are required to be picked. You can't finish the exam not selecting the correct number of answers for each question.
- It is not indicated, but my questions were obviously grouped by topics.

Worth to read: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/SCJP-FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have standardized testing, there's always room for interpretation failure.

This seems like they have poorly defined what the expectations of the answers are.

That being said, I've met people with certifications that couldn't code their way out of a paper bag, and I know hundreds of rock-star programmers with no certification that get good stuff done.